# Is 'Higgs Boson' called the 'God Particle' because of a book by Leon Lederman?

Tags: physics

Why is 'Higgs Boson' called the 'God Particle'? 
According to Forbes

> The name was the invention of Leon Lederman, himself a great physicist, who used it as the title of a popular book in 1993.

Is this actually true?
Or is there any reason for the particle to be named like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They named it the God Particle because in the book, *The God Particle: If the Universe is the Answer, What is the Question?*, the publisher wouldn't allow them to call it the Goddamn particle. They called it this because of its villainous nature and the expense it is causing. And two, there is a connection, of sorts, to another book, a much older one... Referring to the book of Geneses from the Bible. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). [Wikipedia is a secondary source.](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-wikipedia-a-valid-reference), and it would be better to follow up the sources to link to the original.

Answer (score 6):

This is true.

See [The God particle: if the universe is the answer, what is the question?](http://books.google.ca/books/about/The_God_particle.html?id=15nuAAAAMAAJ).

And [Google ngram viewer results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=God+particle&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CGod%20particle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGod%20Particle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGod%20particle%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Also, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/God_particle):

> Leon Lederman's book The God Particle was apparently thus called at the suggestion of his editor. It is also claimed that Lederman himself dubbed it (the particle) the goddamn particle, for its elusiveness, the term being toned down for public use.